# Selecting the right DV in study of treatment effect on a small sample?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, small-sample

I want to run a simple experiment at work to see if making a single change `F` on a product, has any significant adverse effect on the performance. I need help to design the experiment.

What I have in mind is this: we hire a group of `N` users. Each user is given one product. They test their product before and after enabling the change `F` (imagine a software change). Let's call the product before making the change `A` and after making the change `B`. To get a feedback and calculate some statistics, I have several options:

1. Each user tells us if she preferred `A` or `B` (no ties)
2. Each user tells us if she preferred `A` or `B` or if they rate them the same
3. Each user rates `A` and `B` separately on a small scale (e.g. from 1 to 5)
4. Each user rates `A` and `B` separately on a large scale (e.g. from 1 to 100)

The fact is that I don't have access to a large user base so I want to find the most efficient (powerful?) design. The problem is that it is very expensive to produce lots of units each time we make a new change and testing which involve hiring users is also expensive.

From an engineering point of view, I suspect that the effect of `F` on the product is not measurable by the users. The purpose of the study is (hopefully) to be able to show to the users that incorporating `F` into the system is not making it noticeably worse (think e.g. using \$30 HDMI cables vs overpriced \$500 versions). Later, we'll run a separate set of objective measurements to quantify the effect of `F` (though the results will not be easy to interpret by the end users; thus this study).

So what is the best question I can ask my users (question 1 - 4)? What is the correct statistical test that I can apply? Any thoughts about running such tests with small sample sizes?

I feel that the options 1 or 2 are not ideal since I will have to either analyze the data using a non-parametric test or a proportion test (I don't know which one is the best btw) but that will give me low power. On the other hand, a 1 to 5 or 1 to 100 scale is somewhat artificial since we are basically asking users how they are feeling about the product. However, a parametric paired tests (each user has rating for both `A` and `B`) should be quite efficient.

Notice that we'll ideally run the test in a double-blind setup so I am not worried much about order of the tests, etc.